# Should login of a c++ application be done in a separate thread?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, libcurl

When in an application trying to login by connecting to a php script hosted somewhere on a server, the application stops responding, which is to be expected, but if there is some delay in the connection or response from the php script, the wait gets too long and looks like the application has hanged, which we don't want our user to think.

So is it a good idea to create a new thread just for the purpose, and simply disable the controls on the main application till the response is received ?

I am working in C++ and pure Winapi along with libCurl and oop.

Comment: Using a thread seems like a reasonable approach to me.

Comment: You can also use asynchronous I/O with callbacks.

Comment: You can also make a timeout on the connection, and if the timeout expires advise the user to try at another time.

Comment: @hetepeperfan: If we assume this is a "typical website access", the delays of a few tens to around a second is perfectly "normal" and expected. This could still appear like the application has hung.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I agree, but doesn't the Winapi supports polling on the socket to determine if there is something to read, anyway, there are probably multiple way to handle this type of problems and doing this in a threads, forking the process seems certainly possible as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never do (propably) time-intensive tasks in your main (GUI?)-Thread. Connecting to servers is such a thing. You'll probably get around it by using asynchronous IO (for example callbacks, or non-blocking sockets), but these solutions also just spawn another thread for you.
Do your connection in another thread and disable the controls while connecting, but tell the user the program is doing something (for example by a rotating circle or something). Users hate it when programs seem to do nothing.

Comment: the rotating circle will itself need a separate thread ? How about letting the Main thread blocked during the process, putting a timeout on the connection and create a new thread for the rotating circle animation ? What are the pitfalls of this approach ?

Comment: The application processes it's messages in the main thread, so if you block it, it will still react as if it is not working anymore. On Windows for example there will be a "xy stopped responding" message and most users click on "force close" instead of "wait for it". You should use a (window-system-provided) timer in your main thread which calls a method that rotates the circle by some degrees every 50 milliseconds or so.

Answer (score 2):

libcurl multi interface have the ability to work asynchronously, so instead of having separate thread you'll have to call curl_multi_perform() function until you have the result. It may look strange, but every time you can avoid using threads in your application you win. Threads == bugs that some day will happen, so if possible avoid them. Here is some [basic example](http://www.godpatterns.com/2011/09/asynchronous-non-blocking-curl-multi.html)